# Using jsoup is there a way to get anchor tags that are within div tags with class attribute that have display none style in the css class..?

Tags: css, class, styles, jsoup, extract

I have a document from which I am trying to extract the a tags. Some of them are within div tags that have the class attribute and the class has the display:none property set. They are not hidden using the style attribute in the div tag directly. I want to eliminate those. The css is included in the page using link tag.

Answer (score 0):

Select all `<a>`-tags and search if one of the parents is a `<div>` with the hiding-class:

```
for (Element a : doc.getElementsByTag("a")) {
    for (Element parent : a.parents()) {
        if (parent.tagName().equals("div") && parent.hasClass("hidden")) {
            a.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Or easier - just remove all anchors in a `<div>` with the hiding-class:

```
doc.select("div.hidden a").remove();
```